# Second time Authentication fails Java Mail API

Tags: java, android, email

Well i put my gmail address and my pass in 2 EditTexts and when i click the OK button i try to send a mail in my gmail account with the java mail api. BUT if i put wrong data it doesn't authenticate and thus i do not send the email. If i start again the application and use the real data then it fails to authenticate again. Do i do something wrong or that is the way things done with java mail api? Here is what i use for sending the email:

```
public GmailSender(String user, String password) {
    this.user = user;
    this.password = password;

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, this);

}

protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
}
public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
    message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setDataHandler(handler);
    if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
    else
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
    Transport.send(message);
}

public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {
    private byte[] data;
    private String type;

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type)    {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.type = type;
                                                            }

    public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
                                            }

    public void setType(String type)    {
        this.type = type;
                                        }

    public String getContentType() {
        if (type == null)
            return "application/octet-stream";
        else
            return type;
                                    }

    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException  {
        return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
                                                            }

    public String getName() {
        return "ByteArrayDataSource";
                            }

    public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException    {
        throw new IOException("Not Supported");
                                                                }

}
```

}
Here what i get from logcat

```
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595): println needs a message
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a     message
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:143)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at     stathis.example.teliko.Data.onClick(Data.java:107)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-07 09:58:50.781: E/Validate(595):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Sure, but how exactly do i do that?

Comment: do you have some output in logcat?

Comment: Yes actually i have, i will edit my question to show it

Comment: What i notice though is that when i go to my settings and push the 'clear data' button when i put the right address at the first time it works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is your problem, but the following code is wrong:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
...
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
```

A `Properties` object is a kind of `Map`, and it maps from a `String` to an `Object`.  If you call the `put` method with the same key twice in a row, then the value in the second call *replaces* the value that you added in the first call.

So the above is equivalent to:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
...
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "587");
```

Your "465" entries will be ignored.

Comment: Well you are right but if i use the 465 port only it comes up with the same error!